# data.table::shift type="lag" allowing extending the data

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time-series, data.table

I am using [`data.table::shift`](https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/shift.html) to lag my time series. What I would like now is to expand the dates to account for the shift beyond the time series maximum date.

For example, if I have a monthly time series that ends in May 2023 and I lag it by 3 months, what I would like to obtain is the shifted time series that ends in August 2023.

To complicate things, I have to do this by group.

Let me provide a simple example.

```
library(data.table)

dates <-
  rep(seq.Date(
    from = as.Date("2023-01-01"),
    to = as.Date("2023-05-01"),
    by = "month"
  ), times = 2)
groups <- c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5))
values <- 1:10
data <- data.table(date=dates,group=groups,value=values)
```

If I do `data[, value.lag := shift(value, n = 3), by = group]`, I obtain this, which still ends in May 2023 and is not what I want:

```
date    group   value   value.lag
2023-01-01  a   1   NA
2023-02-01  a   2   NA
2023-03-01  a   3   NA
2023-04-01  a   4   1
2023-05-01  a   5   2
2023-01-01  b   6   NA
2023-02-01  b   7   NA
2023-03-01  b   8   NA
2023-04-01  b   9   6
2023-05-01  b   10  7
```

What I would need instead is this (**column value is optional**, what I really need is value.lag):

```
date    group   value   value.lag
2023-01-01  a   1   NA
2023-02-01  a   2   NA
2023-03-01  a   3   NA
2023-04-01  a   4   1
2023-05-01  a   5   2
2023-06-01  a   NA  3
2023-07-01  a   NA  4
2023-08-01  a   NA  5
2023-01-01  b   6   NA
2023-02-01  b   7   NA
2023-03-01  b   8   NA
2023-04-01  b   9   6
2023-05-01  b   10  7
2023-06-01  b   NA  8
2023-07-01  b   NA  9
2023-08-01  b   NA  10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

rbind(data, data[, tail(.SD, 3) , by = group][, 
          c("date", "value") := list(date %m+% months(3), NA)])[, 
              value.lag := shift(value, n = 3), by = group][order(group, date)]

#>           date group value value.lag
#>  1: 2023-01-01     a     1        NA
#>  2: 2023-02-01     a     2        NA
#>  3: 2023-03-01     a     3        NA
#>  4: 2023-04-01     a     4         1
#>  5: 2023-05-01     a     5         2
#>  6: 2023-06-01     a    NA         3
#>  7: 2023-07-01     a    NA         4
#>  8: 2023-08-01     a    NA         5
#>  9: 2023-01-01     b     6        NA
#> 10: 2023-02-01     b     7        NA
#> 11: 2023-03-01     b     8        NA
#> 12: 2023-04-01     b     9         6
#> 13: 2023-05-01     b    10         7
#> 14: 2023-06-01     b    NA         8
#> 15: 2023-07-01     b    NA         9
#> 16: 2023-08-01     b    NA        10
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>